# Transactional Email API: Emails stuck in Queued status

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, queue

Follow up to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/267474/transactional-email-api-triggeredsend-definition-not-enabled-for-this-route)

I've created a Send Definition, with the key `definition_key`, linked to the Data Extension `data_ext`. In this Data Extension, I've got one record, with the subscriber key `subscriber_key` and the email `email`.

Now, I'm trying to send an email, using the rest API.

I hit the following endpoint POST https://MY_SUBDOMAIN.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/email/messages/f4fe74b7-c3c0-4e5a-9f49-b63a641109a2

with the following payload:

```
{
  "definitionKey": "definition_key",
  "recipient":
  {
      "contactKey": "subscriber_key",
      "to": "email",
      "attributes": {
          "CompanyID": "company_id",
          "EmailAddress": "email"
      }
  }
}
```

This request ends up in a 202 Status, but, after doing multiple GET for the same resource, and checking the queue associated with the definition, it seems that the email is stuck in `EmailQueued` status.

=> Could it be a misconfiguration issue from the MC interface ? (I doubt it because the transactional API and the UI don't seem to be correlated)

Or is my payload incomplete, despite the 202 status ?

Thanks

Comment: Are records being created in the Data Extension? If so, can you try to preview the email against one of the records to see, whether it renders correctly? If any AmpScript errors are in the email, it might end up in EmailQueued status

Comment: In the data extension `data_ext` linked to the send definition, there is 1 record (the subscriber to which I want to send the email)
In the MC interface, the preview and sending work well.
The template I'm using does not contain any AMPScript

In the "attributes" field of the payload, do I need to specify all of the values contained in the Data Extension Row ?

Comment: The data extension fields need to correspond 1:1 to your payload (i.e. DE field names = fields in API call). This can also be a source of the issue

Comment: Just to check for the more basic issue: Did you start the Triggered Send, by marking it and clicking Start/Restart button in the Triggered Send overview?

Comment: My triggered send was created with the REST API, and I cannot view it in the interface. Yet, when I go a `GET /email/definitions/{my_definition}`, the status is `Active`. I guess it's the equivalent of having it started in the interface

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95614/discussion-between-ismail-mourtada-and-lukas-lunow).

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by removing the `DataExtension` attribute from the Triggered Send Definition. In fact, I don't need this attribute, because all that matters is the Subscriber Key. If I have some Subscriber Attributes to specify, I can still copy the data from my Data Extension Row, without forcibly specifying which Data Extension it belongs to